# How to show that any greedy algorithm gives a 2-approximation for the best min weighted vertex cover

Tags: algorithms, approximation, weighted-graphs, vertex-cover

The problem I am trying to solve is that there is an underlying undirected graph `G = (V, E)` with weights on the vertices, where the weight on vertex `v` is
denoted by `wv = d(v)` (the degree of the vertex). My goal is to find a vertex cover set `U` (a set where for every `e = (u, v)`, one of vertices `u, v` is in `U`) with the minimal total weight possible.

I have to show that any greedy algorithm, gives a 2-approximation to the best vertex cover.

I can't seem to come up with an idea for such an algorithm. The best I could think of is to select the vertex with minimum weight first and then continue like any greedy algorithm by picking two vertices where edges have not been covered.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

[Edit] Since the downvotes for no reason, here's the whole text (Whicih is the same as question text I wrote) we got for the exercise and can't seem to figure out how to even approach to prove.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but why was this downvoted? What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is the same question as [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156548/how-can-i-prove-that-any-greedy-algorithms-provides-a-2-approximation-to-the-bes) and it is as unclear. Your question is "prove for any greedy algorithm", then you are considering a specific algorithm. What is it, an existential question or a universal question? How could any greedy algorithm work when the naive greedy algorithm selecting all vertices is clearly not a $2$-approximation?

Comment: Because that's the only data we have in the original question and we can't seem to figure out exactly. Moreover, I am not considering a specific algorithm, that was an example of what I can think of as the best algorithm. Iteratively selecting vertices with minimum weights on it.

If not algorithm, what are the other ways to show that any greedy approach would result in 2 approx for best vertex cover?

I don't understand how silently downvoting answers or adds to the problem.

Comment: See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/yet-another-case-of-why-was-my-question-downvoted) and [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397). No one has to explain why they downvoted a question and, as a matter of fact, I did explain, so I don't think this is "silently downvoting".

Comment: Sorry, your explanation came later and I accept it as the correct answer. Sorry for being harsh, HW was getting on my nerves and seeing the downvotes infuriated me. Thanks for great help.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: "Any greedy algorithm"? I can imagine proving that there is a greedy algorithm, or that one specific algorithm gives a two approximation, but _any_? Like the TSP greedy algorithm "from the current town, go to the town that is furthest away".

Comment: That's what I am confused about. How can we prove 'any greedy algorithm' maybe there's a trick to this but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to re-read the question multiple times to understand what you wanted to do, but I think I finally understood.

To prove that any greedy algorithm returns a $2$-approximation is the same as showing that any vertex cover is a $2$-approximation (assuming that any greedy algorithm returns a vertex cover, which is not clear to me, depending on how you define the family of greedy algorithms). Since any vertex cover is a subset of the set of all vertices, the problem is equivalent to proving that the set of all vertices is a $2$-approximation.

Since the weight of each vertex is its degree, if each edge is covered, then at least half of the degrees are "covered" (meaning that if $C$ is a vertex cover, then $\sum\limits_{v\in C}\deg(v) \geqslant \frac12 \sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v)$), because an edge increases the degree of each of its extremities of 1.

I honestly don't find the exercise well formulated using greedy algorithms (surely because there is no very formal way to define a greedy algorithm). It would have been clearer, less confusing, to ask to prove that $V$ itself or any vertex cover is a $2$-approximation.

Comment: I believe your explanation is the best one so far. Since even minimum of the degree of vertex cover will have all edges covered and greedy approach wants us to consider atleast two vertices in the starting it will end up with a 2 approx. 
to conclude it still remains how to show 'any' greedy approach would end up with same result. maybe we don't know for this since its an NP-complete problem